# How to pass the variadic parameters to a function pointer?

Tags: c, optional-parameters, variadic-functions

What is the right way to implemet a function with this declaration:

```
void variadicFunction(int (*someFunction)(), ...)
```

such that it will call the function:

```
someFunction(...)
```

where `...`are the variadic parameters given to variadicFunction.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the full prototype of someFunction? You are omitting parameters, which is a dangerous obsolete variant.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. You need to rewrite `someFunction` to receive a `va_args` instead.

Comment: I wanted to make a general driver function for a specific project's unit testing. Thanks for the answers.